# Pass object as command line arg

Tags: c#

I have a parent application that i want it to run a child application and passing a complex object to it in order for the child to perform. I have searched here and there and came up with these solutions which doesn't work for me for the following reason(s)

Using Json.Net to serialize/deserialize: This doesn't work because i have Abstract and Interfaces that JSON.Net can't determine how to deserialize and it seems complicated to force it to do so.

Using IPC: still i need to add the [Serializable] attribute to every class in my application which is really too hard due to the size of the project.

Remoting: Seems too much for the simple task i want to perform.

What i need ?

Child application pseudo code

```
static void Main(ComplexObject obj)
{
     //Here i got my object!.... (passed from parent by Process.Start's args)
}
```

Comment: Json or xml is a good approach. But if your model has inheritance issues, either attribute it with the required Json.net attributes or serialize manually using JsonWriter or XmlWriter or the like.

Comment: @zaitsman is there any library or way to just share my object between appdomains ?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but are you sure it needs to be a separate process?

Answer (score 5):

I think you've hit on the two main ways to share objects between processes in your question: serialization or remote access. I will try to explain why there is no "easier" way to do it and why these solutions work.

Imagine a complex object: it hold references to other objects (possibly interfaces/base/abstract classes), resource handles like files and locks, etc. All these things live in the parent process, and cannot be directly accessed by the child process. That's just how modern operating systems work.

One way to solve this problem is to find all the pieces[1], gather them up[2], write them down in a way that makes sense to another process[3] and pass them to the child. This is essentially what serialization does, regardless if you are using JSON, XML, or a binary data file.

Details:

1. If you have a base class pointer, you need to figure out the concrete (real) class of the object to find all its pieces (members) because the base represents only part of the object. Fortunately, C# reflection makes this part less difficult.
2. If you have a cycle in your object graph (object A references B which references A) then you have to be careful how exactly you gather objects or you'll end up in an infinite loop. This kind of cycle can easily happen when object A has a member B which holds a listener/delegate from object A.
3. Files, locks, database connections, and other resources are often referenced by process-specific handles (numbers) that will make no sense to a another process.

The other way to do this is to access the object in the parent process "remotely". Imagine that the child process is a client and the parent process is a server. You could write an interface in the parent that exposes methods of the object to the child. That way the child can use the object without actually owning it. This approach may be appropriate when the object has state and resources that cannot be shared.

I hope gives an idea of what possible solutions have to deal with, and helps you pick a strategy that works for your project.

Comment: Any links on how to expose an object for the child process ?